# How to syntax highlight line with three parts?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am trying to highlight lines like these:

```
-> Some text without a domain
-> Some other text with a domain (example.com)
```

I would like:

a) the leading "->" not to be highlighted;
b) the text to be highlighted with, say, `Underlined`;
c) and the domain if given to be highlighted with, say, `Comment`.

This achieves (a) and (b) but not (c):

```
syntax region MyLink start=/^-> /hs=e end=/\v(\s\(\a+[.]\a{2,3}\))?$/he=s-1
highlight link MyLink Underlined
syntax match Domain /\v\(\a+[.]\a{2,3}\)/
highlight link Domain Comment
```

I have tried add `contained` and `contains` etc but haven't quite found the right answer.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track! You just need to *either*:

Add `containedin=MyLink` to your definition of `Domain`:

```
syntax match Domain /\v\(\a+[.]\a{2,3}\)/ containedin=MyLink
```

*or*:

Add `contains=Domain` to your definition of `MyLink`:

```
syntax region MyLink start=/^-> /hs=e end=/\v(\s\(\a+[.]\a{2,3}\))?$/he=s-1 contains=Domain
```